# Why does this Java code compile and run? I do not understand it

Tags: java, private

I am studying for my certification exam, and I run into this example that compiles and runs, but the problem is that I do not think that it should compile, since the method is private and we are trying to invoke a private method from an instance of the class.  Can someone please explain to me why it works?

Here is the code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test instance = new Test();
        System.out.println(instance.number());
    }

    /* protected */ private int number() {
        try {
            new RuntimeException();
        } finally {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That method isn't `private`. It says right there that it's `protected`.

Comment: First: the message is *protected* and not private. Second: even if it _was_ private you can still access it from within any method of the defining class. private means "class private" not "instance private"

Comment: In any case, you're working in the class that the method is defined in, so there's absolutely no reason that you couldn't access that method.

Comment: Duh...I guess I need coffee today...I had changed the example to use protected instead of private, and I just realized that it works in the main method because we are still inside the Test class....:)  Thank you so much for such quick responses...I feel somewhat obtuse after asking this question...:)

Comment: The interesting question is why it prints 1 ;) Good look for your exam.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, and thank you a_horse...and user35... for taking the time to respond.  Cheers.

Comment: I have edited making the method private, so that the code matches the question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The private methods and fields are accessible anywhere from the declaring class, even if called not from inside the instance method:

```
   class Test {
      private void doThis() {};

      public static void main() {  
         Test a = new Test();
         Test b = new Test();

         a.doThis(); // No problem
         b.doThis(); // No problem
      }
   }
```

P.S. The method in your code was initially `protected`, not `private` (protected methods are accessible anywhere in the same package and also outside the package in derived classes). I have edited to make it `private` now. Also such code compiles and runs.

Answer (score 3):

I will try, remember that a finally block is guaranteed to run (unless you call `System.exit`).

```
public class Test { 
  public static void main( String[] args) { 
    Test instance = new Test();  // <-- instantiate a Test instance.
    System.out.println( instance.number());  // call get number method. gets 1
  } 
  protected int number() { 
    try { 
      /* throw */ new RuntimeException(); // instantiates an unchecked exception.
      // even if you threw it, it wouldn't matter....
      // even if you did return 0;
    } finally { 
      return 1; // swallows the unchecked exception and returns 1.
    } 
  }
```

}

Comment: `new RuntimeException();` actually doesn't throw a runtime exception, it only instantiates a new one.

Comment: @niiru Good catch, but it doesn't matter... it would still return 1.

Comment: Agreed 100%! I've seen some hard-to-trace bugs arise when people accidentally initialize exceptions when they meant to throw them, though...

Answer (score 2):

As the protected class is in the same package/class or subclass then the instance that is calling it, there is no problem.

In fact protected is less restrictive then private.

[In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)